# Modal image close preview from w3schools.com not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

Heres the link to the w3 page https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp, and all the changes made is only in the javascript. Note that the one in the w3 page isnt working so i had to find a solution from this page and found this https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/f1zav0ge/ and i took only the javascript code from here, and both still doesnt work

Heres the html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Gallery | safsafa</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="gallery.css">
        <link rel = "icon" href =  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRUXLH90QAaWzieHLTW9BxxNvSKIEhAzRzJ1g&usqp=CAU" type = "image/x-icon"> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            
                <h1><span><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i> fsasaf</span></h1>
                    <ul class="nav_links">
                        <li><a href="tesAbc.html" >Home</a></li><li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li><li><a href="#">Showcase</a></li><li><a href="#">About</a></li><li class="nav-seperator">|</li>
                    </ul>
        </header>
        <main>
            <div class="container">
            
            <h2>//CLICK THESE IMAGES</h2><br>
            <img class="myImages" id="myImg" src="image/racoon.jpg" alt="A Racoon" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
            <img class="myImages" id="myImg" src="image/hamster.jpg" alt="A Hamster" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
            <img class="myImages"id="myImg" src="image/hedgehog.jpg" alt="A Hedgehog" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
            <img class="myImages" id="myImg" src="image/artic_fox.jpg" alt="An Artic Fox" style="width:100%;max-width:300px">
            <!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
            <div id="caption"></div>
            </div>
            
            </div>
        </main>
        
        <script>
            window.addEventListener('scroll',function(){
                var header = document.querySelector("header");
                header.classList.toggle('sticky',window.scrollY > 0)
            })
        </script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="aos.js"></script>
          <script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.js"></script>
  <script>
    AOS.init();
  </script>
  <script>
// create references to the modal...
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
// to all images -- note I'm using a class!
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('myImages');
// the image in the modal
var modalImg = document.getElementById("img01");
// and the caption in the modal
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

// Go through all of the images with our custom class
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  // and attach our click listener for this image.
  img.onclick = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

And heres the css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Heebo:wght@500&display=swap');

*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}

body{
    background-color: #9dc1fc;
}
header{

    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:;
    transition: 0.6s;
    z-index:10000000;
}
header span{
    font-family:Poppins, sans-serif;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 125%;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding-left: 70px;
}
header .nav-seperator{
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
}


header span{
    letter-spacing:-2px;
    font-size: 115%;
    color: blackc;
}
header ul{
    font-family:Heebo, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 6200;
    font-size: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 100px;

}
header li{
    display: inline-block;
    
}
header li a{
    margin-right:30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
header li a:hover{
    color: #fe6e00;
}

header{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}
header.sticky{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5)
}
header.sticky ul li a{
    color: white;
}
header.sticky span{
    color: white;
}
header.sticky .nav-seperator{
    color: white;
}
/* MAIN CONTAINER*/
main .container{
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    text-align:center;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color:black;
    font-family: Poppins;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 900;
}
#myImg {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

/* Caption of Modal Image (Image Text) - Same Width as the Image */
#caption {
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 700px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px 0;
  height: 150px;
}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)}
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the close button on the modal window remains below the navigation and therefore cannot be clicked. In order to be able to close the modal it is necessary to make these two changes in CSS:

On style `header` set `z-index: 10;`

On style `.modal` set `z-index: 11;`

This change he made so that when the modal window opens it will stand above the navigation and the "close" button can be clicked.